# Gradle multiple jars from single source folder

Tags: java, jar, gradle

As for now we have a project structure with single source folder named `src`, which contains  source code for three modules. What I want to do is:

1) Compile source code. This is easily done with sourceSets definition:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

2) Put compilation results into three jars. I am doing this via three 'jar' type tasks:

I am doing this now via three separate tasks:

- util.jar

  ```
  task utilJar(type: Jar) {
      from(sourceSets.main.output) {
          include "my/util/package/**"
      }
  }
  ```
- client.jar

  ```
  task clientJar(type: Jar) {
      from(sourceSets.main.output) {
          include "my/client/package/**"
      }
  }
  ```
- server.jar

  ```
  task serverJar(type: Jar) {
      from(sourceSets.main.output) {
          include "**"
      }
      excludes.addAll(utilJar.includes)
      excludes.addAll(clientJar.includes)
  }
  ```

The thing is that `server.jar` should contain all classes that are not contained within `client.jar` and `util.jar`. In ant build script we solve this problem by using `difference` ant task. How this can be done in gradle (my current approach doesn't work)?

Maybe my approach is completely wrong. Please advice.

P.S. as for now we CAN NOT change the project source code folder structure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I will post my working solution here as an answer (I've got a hint on gradle's forum).

The scopes in gradle are very strange thing :) I thought that every task definition creates an object of some 'Task' class, which is something like 'JarTask' in this particular case. Then I can access any property of the class from anywhere in my build.gradle script. However, I found the only place where I can see the patterns, which are included in jar file - inside a `from` block of a task. So my working solution for now is to:

1) Define a project-level collection to contain patterns to be excluded from `server.jar`

2) Exclude all patterns in `from` block of `serverJar` task.

Please see final version below

```
sourceSets {  
    main {  
        java {  
            srcDir 'src'  
        }  
    }  
} 

// holds classes included into client.jar and util.jar, so they are to be excluded from server.jar
ext.serverExcludes = []

// util.jar
task utilJar(type: Jar) {  
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {  
        include "my/util/package/**" 
        project.ext.serverExcludes.addAll(includes)
    }  
}

// client.jar
task clientJar(type: Jar) {  
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {  
        include "my/client/package/**"
        project.ext.serverExcludes.addAll(includes)
    }  
}

// server.jar
task serverJar(type: Jar) {  
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {  
        exclude project.ext.serverExcludes
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is great, but how do you refer to the separate `.jar` files from other projects - e.g. how could you pull in `client.jar` into another subproject?

Comment: @z0r we are simply publishing artifacts to the repository and then using them as dependencies in subprojects. 

P.S. sorry for the delay in response.

Answer (score 33):

I think the approach is wrong. I recommend making a project with 3 sub projects.

```
project
- util
- server (depends on util)
- client (depends on util)
```

If for some reason you cannot change the class structure use this kind of build files:

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'util', 'client', 'server'
```

**build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

project(':util') {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir '../src'
                include 'util/**'
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':server') {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir '../src'
                include 'server/**'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile project(':util')
    }
}

project(':client') {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir '../src'
                include 'client/**'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile project(':util')
    }
}
```

You still need directories for subprojects but the sources are in one place as you wanted.

When you run `gradle assemble` you will have 3 jars with separate set of classes. The advantage of this solution is that we make a proper Gradle multi module project with correct dependencies, not just tasks for building jars.

Please read [Multi-Project Builds](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've thought about such approach, but it is very desirable to not change the directory structure at all. The main reason is that we have lots of SVN branches (more than fifty) and it should be a real pain to merge them after directory structure changes (you know, tree conflicts). Another reason is that `util` and `client` depend on each other, so I guess they should be in a separate module, which brings same problem. I know that this is a mess in our source code structure design, but I believe gradle can do everything that ant can :)

Comment: @vitalidze The solution I proposed is not changing directory structure.  Are additional empty directories a problem? Do you have dependency cycles?

Comment: The thing is that classes are not separated by folders (i.e. client, server, util). For example, I include into client jar 'a/b' and 'z/x/y', util includes 'q/w/e', and server should include all rest classes, which may be under 'a', 'z', 'z/x', 'q', 'q/w'.

Comment: @vitalidze You can still do a lot using the include and exclude patterns. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html

Comment: I downvoted this because there are situations where you need a single project to produce multiple artifacts and that is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: If you're using Gradle >= 3, the `compile` configuration has been deprecated in favor or `implementation`. See [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#new_configurations).

Answer (score 4):

We have the same problem at my company, ie. legacy code that is difficult to migrate into a "good" project structure, and the need to build several jars from the same codebase. We decided to define different sourceSets and build each of the sourceSets using standard Gradle.

We then use iterators to add jar- and javadoc-tasks for each sourceSet:

```
sourceSets.all { SourceSet sourceSet ->
    Task jarTask = tasks.create("jar" + sourceSet.name, Jar.class)
    jarTask.from(sourceSet.output)
    // Configure other jar task properties: group, description, manifest etc

    Task javadocTask = tasks.create("javadoc" + sourceSet.name, Javadoc.class)
    javadocTask.setClasspath(sourceSet.output + sourceSet.compileClasspath)
    javadocTask.setSource(sourceSet.allJava)
    // Extra config for the javadoc task: group, description etc

    Task javadocJarTask = tasks.create("javadocJar" + sourceSet.name, Jar.class)
    javadocJarTask.setClassifier("javadoc") // adds "-javadoc" to the name of the jar
    javadocJarTask.from(javadocTask.outputs)
    // Add extra config: group, description, manifest etc
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree in principal with the accepted answer too.
I found a project where the client requires two JAR essentially of the same file except the Manifest is different only by the Class-Path key.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": platformMainClass,
                "Implementation-Title": platformDisplayName,
                "Implementation-Description": platformDescription,
                "Platform-Version": platformVersion,
                "Implementation-Version": version,
                "Build-Assembly-User": System.getProperty("user.name"),
                "Build-Assembly-Date": new java.util.Date().toString(),
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { "lib/"+it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }

    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    exclude( [ 'log4j*.properties', 'uk/gov/acme/secret/product/server/**' ])
}
```

The same manifest and the source code then is:

```
task applicationClientJar(type: Jar, description: "Creates the Application  Client JAR file.") {
    dependsOn compileJava
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": platformMainClass,
                "Implementation-Title": platformDisplayName,
                "Implementation-Description": platformDescription,
                "Platform-Version": platformVersion,
                "Implementation-Version": version,
                "Assembly-Date": new java.util.Date().toString()
        )
    }
    archiveName = "acme-client-${platformVersion}.jar"
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/libs")
    from sourceSets.main.output

    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    exclude( [ 'log4j*.properties', 'uk/gov/acme/secret/product/server/**'     }
```

So Grzegorz notation is correct, because the Gradle should know there are two different JAR with GAVs. Multi-module is the preferred option.

```
compile "uk.gov.acme.secret:acme:1.0"  // CORE
compile "uk.gov.acme.secret:acme-client:1.0"
```

The only way to configure for this is to use the Multi-Module Gradle project and then add a compile and/or deploy dependency to the core / main project.

```
project(':common:acme-micro-service-webapp') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':common:acme-core')
    }
}
```

Inside the 'acme-micro-service-webapp' project, this ensures that the dependent 'common:acme-core' is compiled first.

PS: I am still trying to figure out a better solution.

PS PS: If you are using Maven as well as, it may be possible to hook on the `install' task.

Comment: This answer is pretty slick if the project directory structure must stay the same (like for some non-standard project structure). Grzegorz Żur's answer is a clean way to go, but requires modifying the directory structure, which was not an option for me. I just a had more than one class with a main function and I needed a jar per one of those. I would add this `tasks.build.dependsOn(['JarOne', 'JarTwo', 'applicationClientJar'])` to the build.gradle file to make sure a simple `gradle build` adds the jar tasks to its procedure.