# Gradle - generating and installing multiple jar from single project

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm able to build the jars I need - but using `gradle install` I get the error

> A POM cannot have multiple artifacts with the same type and
>   classifier. Alr eady have MavenArtifact a:jar:jar:null, trying to add
>   MavenArtifact a:jar:jar:null.

As per the docs, setting a different **`baseName`** for each archive would resolve this but it doesnt.

I've tried Gradle 2.2.1 in case that matters.

Relevant build.gradle

```
task package1 (type: Jar) {
    baseName = "a1"
    include "**/packageA/**"
}

task package2 (type: Jar) {
    baseName "a2"
    include "**/packageB/**"
}

task package3 (type: Jar) {
    baseName "a3"
    include "**/packageC/**"
}
artifacts{
    archives package1,package2,package3

}
```

I dont want to set different classifier or type for Maven POMs to be different. Is that the only option?

Other references:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_publish_multiple_artifacts_w_sources_per_project

Comment: One of the purposes of build tools is being able to uniquely identify each artefact. If you declare multiple JARs having the same coordinates (group and artefact IDs), and try to use them as a dependency to antoher project, the build tool won't know what to include, because it's designed to handle a single artefact for a set of coordinates.

Comment: @Zoltán: I understood changing the baseName = changing the Artifact ID so its not the same coordinates

Comment: In general it seems strange to create multiple jar from single codebase. Why don'y you change the artifactId for every jar being built?

Comment: @Opal: I am changing the artfiactId - that is what baseName is supposed to do isnt it?

Comment: @JoseK, not exactly. `baseName` it's a jar filename whereas artifactId, group and version define and unique artifact. The artifacts prepared are not unique in terms of maven structure. What are you trying to achieve? Why so many jars?

Comment: @Opal: because we have to provide each split jar to different consumers to use. We dont want to create each as a separate sub-project in gradle. Each package has only 5-6 classes. I ahve seen other quesitons on similar lines http://stackoverflow.com/q/20008324/289396 so ths seems common requirement

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using `gradle publish` as per the method described at https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

```
task package1 (type: Jar) {
    baseName "a1"
    version "0.1"
    from (sourceSets.main.output){
    include "com/packagea/**"
    }
}

task package2 (type: Jar) {
    baseName "a2"
    from (sourceSets.main.output){
    include "com/packageb/**"
    }
}

// We use the publishing task instead of gradle install to deploy the jar into the local MAVENREPO
publishing {
    publications {
        publisha1(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.my'
            artifactId 'a1'
            version '0.1'
            artifact package1 
        }
        publishb1(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.my'
            artifactId 'b1'
            version '0.1'
            artifact package2 
        }
}
```