# Refer to custom jar file in a different subproject

Tags: java, gradle, jar

The post [Gradle multiple jars from single source folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034529/320036) discusses how to produce multiple `.jar` files. But how can you depend on those `.jar` files in other subprojects of a multi-project build?

For example, suppose I have project structure like this:

```
./
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
├── foo/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── main/java/
│   │   └── plugins/java/
│   └── build.gradle
└── bar/
    ├── src/main/java/
    └── build.gradle
```

`foo/build.gradle` builds an extra `.jar` with this task:

```
sourceSets {
    plugins
}
task pluginsJar(type: Jar) {  
    from sourceSets.plugins.output
}
```

What can I put in `bar/build.gradle` to make `bar` depend on `plugins.jar`? I tried doing this:

```
dependencies {
    runtime project(':foo:plugins')
}
```

But Gradle says:

> Project with path ':foo:plugins' could not be found in project ':bar'

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to publish them as jars to have them as dependencies. In order to make `foo` a dependency of `bar` this is all you need. Some of the ways are listed below depending ont he configuration you need. See my link below the examples.

```
// Compiles for test only
dependencies {
    testCompile project(':foo')
}

// To have the dependency compiled in the project, if you make a stand alow jar then you will need to zip the files in the "Jar" task.
dependencies {
    compile project(':foo')
}

dependencies {
    runtime project(':foo')
}

// 2.13 gradle only - Allow to compile the project and load the jar from a source and add it to the classpath while the application is running
dependencies {
    compileOnly project(':foo')
}
```

[Chapter 23. Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

EDIT: The most effect way is using gradles built multi module capabilities. You will be able to manage each plugin as a unit within the main project and be able to publish each plugins jar as a bulk operation or with specific parameters that will not effect the other plugins or main application. One you have this establish you can call the `jar` task on the base project and all subjects will be built. You can load the plugins dynamically at application start or while its running.

[Chapter 24. Multi-project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Here are two examples.

```
RootModule/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  ApplicationModule/
    build.gradle
  Plugin1Module/
    build.gradle
  Plugin2Module/
    build.gradle
  Plugin3Module/
    build.gradle
```

or

```
   Project 1 main application:
    ApplicationModule/
      build.gradle
      settings.gradle

   Project 2 plugins: (dependency on 1 API jar)
   RootModule/
      build.gradle
      settings.gradle
      Plugin1Module/
        build.gradle
      Plugin2Module/
        build.gradle
      Plugin3Module/
        build.gradle     
      Plugin4Module/
        build.gradle
      Plugin5Module/
        build.gradle
      Plugin6Module/
        build.gradle
```

Comment: OK, but suppose the source for `server` is not part of the `main` source set (updated question to show this). If I just depend on `project(':foo')`, only the `main` source set gets included. How can I depend on `server` as well?

Comment: Why would you structure it this way? I just re-looked at your structure. I am asking to see what your really trying to achieve overall. Also you cannot access server through `:foo:server` unless server is set up in your settings file as a individual module.

Comment: My [actual project](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/tree/a4bd29ba7904a42d5d24f6eb3106fb68c8cb9711/src/rsaquery) is an image processing system. The `main` source set contains the image processing system. Then I have a `filter` source set that provides a set of plugins (image processing operations). I want them separate to make it clear that they could be replaced with different plugins. I suppose I could use a separate project, but it doesn't quite feel like it warrants it. What are source sets for, if not doing this kind of thing? (honest question)

Comment: @z0r The quickest and easiest way using gradle would be to have a Single project or Two, One main Application, One Plugins or Just combined. But each plugin should be its own module in a multi module project. Each one could and may have its own dependencies as well. When using multi module project you can easily publish all of the jars at one time. Using gradle the way your trying too, is why there are multi module. I will edit my answer to include some references.