# How to build 2 jar artifacts using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am currently building a jar using Gradle. I also generate source and javadoc jars. So far everything is by the book.

Now I want to create an additional jar, that has different content (few classes ignored). This jar should be published using a *classifier*.

Snippets from `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'osgi'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'
configurations {
    published
}
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives jar
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar

    published jar
    published sourcesJar
    published javadocJar
}
```

I am not able to create an additional jar that is going to have everything: manifest updated by OSGI plugin, POM file updated, and signed. I am able to produce an additional JAR, but that jar is just a simple archive, and not signed/updated by plugins etc.

How to create an additional jar that is going to be named with classifier but treated as the regular jar (signed, uploaded to maven central, etc...)?

My try:

```
configure (java8Modules()) {
    configurations {
        java8
    }
    task code8Jar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
        classifier = 'java8'
        from sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
    }
    artifacts {
        java8 code8Jar
        published code8Jar
    }
}
```

gives me a jar, but it is not signed, and manifest is not modified.

Comment: Did you try solutions from similar questions like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008324/gradle-multiple-jars-from-single-source-folder