# Can Gradle produce multiple Kotlin Native binaries (for one OS)?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-native

Can I convince Gradle to produce multiple binaries? I have several Kotlin packages with files that have a proper "fun main(...)" but the default IntelliJ build.gradle file only allows me to specifiy one "compilations.main.entryPoint".
I could put the main functions into Kotlin classes or objects if that would help.

Changing the entryPoint argument to an array did not work :)

If it's not currently possible, is it a general limitation of Gradle or only of the "kotlin-multiplatform" plugin?

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.11'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        // For ARM, preset should be changed to presets.iosArm32 or presets.iosArm64
        // For Linux, preset should be changed to e.g. presets.linuxX64
        // For MacOS, preset should be changed to e.g. presets.macosX64
        fromPreset(presets.mingwX64, 'mingw')

        configure([mingw]) {
            // Comment to generate Kotlin/Native library (KLIB) instead of executable file:
            compilations.main.outputKinds('executable')
            // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
            compilations.main.entryPoint = 'hello.main'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
        // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.
        mingwMain {
        }
        mingwTest {
        }
    }
}

task runProgram {
    def buildType = 'debug' // 'release' - Change to 'debug' to run application with debug symbols.
    dependsOn "link${buildType.capitalize()}ExecutableMingw"
    doLast {
        def programFile = kotlin.targets.mingw.compilations.main.getBinary('EXECUTABLE', buildType)
        exec {
            executable programFile
            args ''
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one OS? Probably. But remember; You're working closely with native code here, which means less platform compatibility. AFAIK, a Kotlin Native Windows executable will not work on Linux, and you cannot compile a Linux executable on Windows because of missing native libraries for the platform. I might be wrong though, not that used to Kotlin Native.

Comment: To clarify: I was asking for several binaries for one OS. Multi-OS is currently not of interest to me.

Comment: In that case, depending on your use, you might be looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034529/6296561 - it's for Java, but since it's still Gradle, I'd assume you should get some code similar to that

Comment: Thanks for the link. That might work if one knows enough about Gradle. But I guess the answer to my original question is that the plugin currently simply does not support multiple binaries.

Answer (score 3):

In https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2505 I've just got the answer that this will be possible with Kotlin Native 1.3.20!